# Calling removeAllViews(); still results in IllegalStateException:You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, fatal-error, illegalstateexception

I'm not sure why this is happening but I'm getting an error stating: Calling `layout.removeAllViews();` still results in `IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent.` You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

The strange part is I've called: removeAllViews(); before adding a new one:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.download);
```

...

```
    ImageView imageViewz = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6); 
            Picasso.with(context).load(background).into(imageViewz);

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(Download.this);
                layout.setId(R.id.download);
                LayoutParams layoutParams 
                 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams 
                 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                imageViewz.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
                layout.removeAllViews();
                layout.addView(imageViewz);
                setContentView(layout);
```

Yet I still get the fatal error...so I'm not sure exactly why this is happening.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please post your entire stack trace. My guess is that your problem is not with `layout`, but rather with `imageViewz`.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare - Let me know if this is enough detail for you - http://pastebin.com/4uWdz7Zq (BTW line 154 is layout.addView(imageViewz);)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with `layout`. Your problem is with `imageViewz`. It already has a parent, and that is what is triggering your exception. You need to remove `imageViewz` from its current parent before you add it to `layout`.

Comment: I truly appreciate the insight @CommonsWare. I tried as you suggested - however I'm still getting the same error on the same line.... I tried 3 implementations - none seem to be working - mind taking a look for a second? http://pastebin.com/fhEMG2Ug

Comment: @NoobDev910: You are attempting to remove `imageViewz` from `layout`. You just created `layout` a few lines earlier. You know that `layout` is not `imageViewz`'s current parent.

Comment: Got it. (I appreciate the help) Just out of curiosity... shouldn't this resolve this issue?    layout.removeAllViews();
         layout.addView(imageViewz);
         setContentView(layout); (It's still crashing at the same point)

Comment: @NoobDev910: "shouldn't this resolve this issue?" -- no. `imageViewz` has a parent. **That parent is not `layout`**, because you just created the `layout` object. Hence, calling `removeAllViews()` on `layout` **will have no effect on `imageViewz`**. *You* were the one who put `imageViewz` in another parent. *You* are the one who has to determine what that parent is (e.g., call `getParent()` on `imageViewz`). And *you* are the one who has to the *that parent* (which, I repeat, is not your newly-created `layout`) to remove `imageViewz` from its list of children.