# App crash on second call of addview

Tags: java, android, imageview, scrollview

While learning I try to build a simple app which shows some images from a folder in a scrollview.

However my app crashes on the second click of this item in a row.
removeAllViews() in the onOptionsItemSelected() did help to prevent the crash if another item is clicked in between.

I did read and try alot, without any success.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is the Code.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    LinearLayout myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
    myLinearLayout.removeAllViews(); //Does help if whatever item is clicked in between.

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_whatever:
            ...
            return true;
        case R.id.action_showScrollview:
            File tumbDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tumbs");
            File[] allTumbs = tumbDir.listFiles();

            for(File tumb : allTumbs){
                ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                Bitmap tumbToShow = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tumb.getAbsolutePath());
                myImageView.setImageBitmap(tumbToShow);
                myLinearLayout.addView(myImageView); //This line causes crash on second click of the showScrollview item in a row
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

edit:

I did now use a workaround to ensure removeAllViews()is performed before the method to add images is called a second time in a row.

These lines remain in onOptionsImtemSelected() of my options menu:

```
 LinearLayout myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
    myLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
```

These lines in the menu item:

```
if (clickedTwice) clickedTwice=false;
else clickedTwice = showMyScrollView();
```

The method with return value true:

```
private boolean showMyScrollView() {

    File tumbDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tumbs");
    File[] allTumbs = tumbDir.listFiles();

    for (File tumb : allTumbs){
        ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(this);
        Bitmap tumbToShow = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tumb.getAbsolutePath());
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(tumbToShow);
        myLinearLayout.addView(myImageView);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now of course every second click of the menu item results in a blank screen, cause the views are removed. On the third click images are added again without trouble.

So i would assume the problem is removeAllViews() is not performed reliably before the following code is processed. 
Maybe something similar as described her:
[Calling removeAllViews(); still results in IllegalStateException:You must call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865059/calling-removeallviews-still-results-in-illegalstateexceptionyou-must-call-r)

Comment: Please post your Exception from the Logcat.

Comment: You're using application context (`getActivityContext()`) instead of activity context (`this`, or `MyClassName.this`); that probably causes the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context for more info. If that's not it, add the error log.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I did change to activity context and read your link.
Was helpful, but did not solve my problem.
As I can not provide an exception from logcat right now, for several reasons, you are probably right to put it on hold.
I was hoping for something very obvious to you, but that does not seem to be the case.
I will report back if I was able to figure out the problem or can provide error log.